# Django check if object in post method have specific value

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using DRF and have object with ManyToMany field. I'd like to check if object that user sent on server contains any pk in that field. Then i want to set boolean field to true in linked object to that ManyToMany.

Models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    child_link = models.ManyToManyField(child, related_name="child")

class Child(models.Model):
    in_use = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Views:

```
class ParentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Parent.objects.filter(user=user)

class ChildView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Child.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Serializers:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = __all__

class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = __all__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case i described, the best solution is to add create() to parent serializer:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(self.data["child_link"]) != 0:
            for id in self.data["child_link"]:
                obj = Child.objects.get(pk=id)
                obj.in_use = True
                obj.save()

        return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
   class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = __all__
```